# Structs of two different types - need to pass one to a function dynamically

Tags: c, struct

Apologies in advance, I have only begun writing C 2 months ago so this is all quite new to me.

I am working on a codebase which already had a solution implemented that needs to be changed.

Currently, one struct holds all the variables for both read/write functionality. This needs to be modified to be two different structs, one for read, one for write.

Below is the current implementation.

```
typedef struct Foo_s
{
 int x;
 int y;
 int z;
}

BarFunction(Foo_s foo) {
 //logic
}
```

Here is the changes that I need to do

```
typedef struct FooRead_s
{
 int x;
 int y;
}

typedef struct FooWrite_s
{
 int z;
}
```

The problem occurs when `BarFunction(Foo_s foo)` is called. It needs to be able to accept either `FooRead_s` or `FooWrite_s` at any given time, even though they are different. How do I allow `BarFunction` to accept both `FooRead_s` and `FooWrite_s`?

Comment: I'm willing to bet the scope of your project includes *splitting the function* as well. So that there are now two functions, one for reading and one for writing.

Comment: You have to refactor your code, a function in C can take either `FooRead_s` or `FooWrite_s`, but not both for the same argument. Split de functionality as well.

Comment: When I asked the architect for more info he was pretty certain that only one function would remain.

Comment: If the architect's suggestion conflicts with how the language itself works than you should go back and iron out the details with them. Maybe there's a misunderstanding between you two.

Answer (score 2):

There are no way in C to distinguish between two or more structures without some selector parameter. One can use union of structs `FooRead_s`, `FooWrite_s` and operation selector.
Selector can be passed as separate argument

```c
typedef union {
    FooRead_s rs;
    FooWrite_s ws;
} Foo_params;

void BarFunction(bool write, Foo_params *foo) {
     if (write) {
         // use foo->ws;
     }
     // ...
}
```

or embedded into structure

```c
typedef struct {
    bool write;
    union {
        FooRead_s rs;
        FooWrite_s ws;
    } params;
} Foo_action;

void BarFunction(Foo_action *foo) {
     if (foo->write) {
         // use foo->params.ws;
     }
}
```

Comment: This is IMHO the expected solution. To OP: If at all possible, please go with the tagged union (i.e., put the `bool write` in the struct) to reduce the risk of caller errors.

Comment: Yes, it is better to keep tag with union in one object.

Answer (score 2):

If we correct your typedefs and write the function to accept a struct passed by pointer, as it ought to be designed, then we end up with this:

```
typedef struct 
{
  int x;
  int y;
} FooRead_s;

typedef struct 
{
  int z;
} FooWrite_s;

void BarFunction_Read (FooRead_s* foo) {
 //logic
}

void BarFunction_Write (FooWrite_s* foo) {
 //logic
}
```

Now if you have the option to use the standard C language, you can then write the function call with generic programming:

```
#define BarFunction(foo)                    \
  _Generic((foo),                           \
           FooRead_s*:  BarFunction_Read,   \
           FooWrite_s*: BarFunction_Write)(foo)

int main (void)
{
  FooRead_s read = {0};
  FooWrite_s write = {0};

  BarFunction(&read);
  BarFunction(&write);
  //BarFunction(read); compiler error here as we should have
}
```

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that, unlike the other answer, this is a compile-time solution.